# How to reach theoretical computer science researchers in China and India? Any equivalent of the DMANET mailing list?

Tags: job-search

An effective way of making researchers in Europe in the field of theoretical computer science aware of open positions, such as PhD positions, Postdoc positions, assistant professor positions, and so on, is to send an announcement to the DMANET mailing list. In addition, this list is often seen by researchers in many other non-European countries.

After posting a job announcement at DMANET, I have received applications from all over the world, but to my surprise, none from  China or India. I wonder if DMANET is as popular in China and in India as it is in Europe, and some other countries among TCS researchers.

So the question is: what are the Chinese and Indian equivalents of the DMANET mailing list? Or if such lists do not exist, what is the most effective way of reaching researchers in TCS in these countries?

**Note:** I'm really only interested in effective ways of reaching researchers in theoretical computer science.